# What's the meaning to chain call and apply together?

Tags: javascript, function, call, apply

I come across this code in jsGarden, and I cannot figure the meaning to chain `call` and `apply` together. Both will execute the function with a given context object, why it could be chained?

```
function Foo() {}

Foo.prototype.method = function(a, b, c) {
    console.log(this, a, b, c);
};

// Create an unbound version of "method" 
// It takes the parameters: this, arg1, arg2...argN
Foo.method = function() {

    // Result: Foo.prototype.method.call(this, arg1, arg2... argN)
    Function.call.apply(Foo.prototype.method, arguments);
};
```

Comment: I'm quite sure you forgot a `prototype` before `.call`

Comment: @Bergi: Actually it makes no difference. As `Function` is a function, it inherits `call` from its own prototype.

Comment: @Ventero: Oh, right, I forgot about that...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's making a call to `call` via `apply`; that is, it's using `call` to call a function ("method"), and it's using `apply` to make the call because it's got the arguments in the form of an (almost) array.

So to take it apart:

```
Function.call
```

That's a reference to the `call()` function available on all Function instances, inherited from the Function prototype.

```
Function.call.apply
```

That's a reference, via the reference to the `call` function, to `apply`.  Because `apply` is referenced via the `call` object, when the call to `apply` is made the `this` value will be a reference to the `call` function.

```
Function.call.apply(Foo.prototype.method, arguments);
```

So we're invoking the `call` function via `apply`, and passing `Foo.prototype.method` to be the `this` value, and the arguments to "Foo.mmethod" as the arguments.

I *think* it's basically the same effect as this:

```
Foo.method = function() {
  var obj = arguments[0], args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
  Foo.prototype.method.apply(obj, args);
}
```

but I'll have to try it to make sure. *edit* Yes that seems to be it.  So I can summarize the point of that trick as being a way to invoke `apply()` when the desired `this` value is the first element of the array holding the parameters.  In other words, usually when you call `apply()` you've got the desired `this` object reference, and you've got the parameters (in an array).  Here, however, since the idea is that you pass in the desired `this` as a parameter, then it needs to be separated out in order for a call to `apply` to be made.  Personally I would do it as in my "translation" because it's a little less mind-bending (to me), but I suppose one could get used to it. Not a common situation, in my experience.

Comment: Additionally, this enforces the usage of `Function.call` and `Function.prototype.apply` in case the provided function has had its `call` method overridden.

Comment: @zzzzBov yes good point; it's not clear to me whether that's an important goal.

Comment: I've never found a need to chain `call()` and `apply()` together. Can anyone suggest a practical example of where this might need to be done?

Comment: @Utkanos I'm scratching my head trying to figure out what the point is too; I understand what's happening but I don't know why it couldn't just be `Foo.prototype.method.call()` after slicing off the first argument.

Comment: @Utkanos, typically this sort of obscure usage would be used by a library doing its best to enforce that the correct method be used the right way, no matter what garbage gets added in JS.

Comment: @Pointy - yeah, that was where I was coming from, too. Glad to know I'm not alone :)

Comment: After reading it several times, finally get the idea. really obscure usage, I mostly do this mannual binding with the way you write.

Answer (score 2):

I think the code should be like this:

```
function Foo() {}

Foo.prototype.method = function(a, b, c) {
 console.log(this, a, b, c);
};

Foo.method = function() {

 //Notice this line:
 Function.apply.call(Foo.prototype.method, this, arguments);
};
```

then

```
Foo.method(1,2,3) => function Foo() {} 1 2 3
```

Other examples:

```
Function.apply.call(Array,this,[1,2]) => [1, 2]
Function.call.apply(Array,this,[1,2]) => [window]
Function.call.call(Array,this,[1,2])  => [[1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) does take an array as the second argument, [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) takes single parameters.

```
 // lets take call,
 var callfn = Function.prototype.call;
 // an ordinary function from elsewhere
 var method = Foo.prototype.method;
 // and apply the arguments object on it:
 callfn.apply(method, arguments);
```

So, the first `arguments` item will be the `this` value of the `method`, and the subsequent will fill the single parameters.

The result is a static function `method` on the `Foo` constructor, that takes a `Foo` instance (or something similiar) as the first argument and applies the prototype `method` on it. A possible usecase were to define a `Object.hasOwnProperty` function, which is normally only available as `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`.

Ultimately, it makes the invocation of the `method` one "prototype" and one "call" shorter if you need to apply it on objects that a) don't inherit it or b) overwrite it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Person.prototype.fullname = function(joiner, options) {
  options = options || { order: "western" };
  var first = options.order === "western" ? this.first : this.last;
  var last =  options.order === "western" ? this.last  : this.first;
  return first + (joiner || " ") + last;
};

// Create an unbound version of "fullname", usable on any object with 'first'
// and 'last' properties passed as the first argument. This wrapper will
// not need to change if fullname changes in number or order of arguments.
Person.fullname = function() {
  // Result: Person.prototype.fullname.call(this, joiner, ..., argN);
  return Function.call.apply(Person.prototype.fullname, arguments);
};
```

The Code from Javascript Garden.

Notice that it state the

```
Function.call.apply(Person.prototype.fullname, arguments);
```

will become this:

```
Person.prototype.fullname.call(this, joiner, ..., argN);
```

It means the **apply()** function will be excuated first, then the **call()** function will be execuated.

Pattern: The **right most** `call() / apply()` will get execuated first

1. So **right most** `apply()` will get executed first
2. The context of the `apply()` becomes the caller of the `call()` function, so now

   ```
   Person.prototype,fullname.call()
   ```
3. `apply()`can only take one single array of parameters, so `apply()` provides `arguments` to the `call()` function, so now

   ```
   Person.prototype,fullname.call(arguments)
   ```

Examples from @foxiris

1st One:

```
Function.apply.call(Array,this,[1,2])
```

1. The **right most** `call()` will get execuated first
2. The context of `call()` becomes the caller of the `apply()` ,so now `Array.apply()`
3. The `call()` can accept multiple arugments, so it can provide `this` and `[1, 2]` to `apply()`, so now `Array.apply(this, [1, 2]);`, which will output `[1, 2]`

2nd One:

```
Function.call.apply(Array,this,[1,2])
```

1. The **right most** `apply()` will get execuated first
2. The context of `apply()` becomes the caller of the `call()` ,so now`Array.call()`
3. The `apply()` can only take one single array parameter, so it can only provide `this` to `call()`, so now `Array.call(this);`, output is `[]`.

3rd One:

```
Function.call.call(Array,this,[1,2])
```

1. The **right most** `call()` will get execuated first
2. The context of `call()`(right most one) becomes the caller of `call()`(the second to the right), so now `Array.call()`
3. The `call()` can take multiple parameters, so it can provide `this` and `[1, 2]` to another `call()`, so now `Array.call(this, [1, 2]);`, output is `[[1, 2]]`.