# call and apply in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the meaning to chain call and apply together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674115/whats-the-meaning-to-chain-call-and-apply-together)

I found some codes like this:

```
function fun() {
    return Function.prototype.call.apply(Array.prototype.slice, arguments);
}
```

I know the `call` and `apply` in js,however I am confused when they come together.

Then I wonder if

```
Function.prototype.call.apply(Array.prototype.slice, arguments)
```

is the same as :

```
Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
```

If not,what does the first line do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alright, let's tackle this problem via substitution. We start with:

```
Function.prototype.call.apply(Array.prototype.slice, arguments);
```

What we know:

1. `Function.prototype.call` is a function.
2. The `this` pointer of `call` points to `Function.prototype`.
3. We use `apply` to change the `this` pointer of `call` to `Array.prototype.slice`.
4. `arguments` is **applied** (not passed as a parameter) to `call`.

Thus the above statement is equivalent to:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments[0], arguments[1], ...);
```

From this we see:

1. `Array.prototype.slice` is a function.
2. The `this` pointer of `slice` points to `Array.prototype`.
3. We use `call` to change the `this` pointer of `slice` to `arguments[0]`.
4. `arguments[1], ...` are passed as parameters to `slice`.

This is the same as:

```
arguments[0].slice(arguments[1], ...);
```

The advantage of this is that we're creating a [fast unbound wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7459769/783743) for `slice` in a single line.

**Edit:** A better way to create fast unbound wrappers is as follows (note that it may not work in some older browsers, but you don't really need to worry about that now - you may always use a [shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) for browsers which don't support `bind`):

```
var slice = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);
```

This is the same as:

```
function slice() {
    return Function.prototype.call.apply(Array.prototype.slice, arguments);
}
```

How it works:

1. `Function.prototype.call` is a function.
2. The `this` pointer of `call` points to `Function.prototype`.
3. We use `bind` to change the `this` pointer of `call` to `Array.prototype.slice`.
4. `bind` returns a function whose `arguments` are **applied** to `call`.

**Bonus:** If your style of programming is highly functional, like mine is, then you would find that is piece of code is very useful:

```
var funct = Function.prototype;
var obj = Object.prototype;
var arr = Array.prototype;

var bind = funct.bind;

var unbind = bind.bind(bind);
var call = unbind(funct.call);
var apply = unbind(funct.apply);

var classOf = call(obj.toString);
var ownPropertyOf = call(obj.hasOwnProperty);
var concatenate = call(arr.concat);
var arrayFrom = call(arr.slice);
```

1. Using this you may easily create unbound wrappers using either `call` or `apply`.
2. You may use `classOf` to get the internal `[[Class]]` of a value.
3. You may use `ownPropertyOf` inside for in loops.
4. You may use `concatenate` to join arrays.
5. You may use `arrayFrom` to create arrays.

Comment: `Function.prototype.bind.call(Function.prototype.bind, Function.prototype.bind)` :-)

Comment: @Bergi - That's the same as `Function.prototype.bind.bind(Function.prototype.bind)`. =)

Comment: is it true? `Function.prototype.bind.bind(Function.prototype.bind) === Function.prototype.bind.bind` From your algorithm... @AaditMShah

Answer (score 1):

With the following line, `.apply` is invoking the `.call` method with the calling context of `.call` being the `.slice` method, and the `arguments` collection passed as individual arguments.

```
Function.prototype.call.apply(Array.prototype.slice, arguments);
```

This effectively gives us this:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2] /*, etc */);
```

This means that `.slice()` will be invoked with the first item in the `arguments` object as the calling context, and the rest of the arguments as the normal arguments.

So if the content of `arguments` is something like this:

```
myarray, 0, 5
```

You're effectively ending up with this:

```
myarray.slice(0, 5)
```

---

It's basically a way of not having to do this:

```
var arr = arguments[0];
var rest = Array.prototype.slice(arguments, 1);

var result = arr.slice.apply(arr, rest);
```