# Javascript Call And Apply used together

Tags: javascript

I know the **call** and **apply** in javascript but how does exactly the difference between javascript Call and Apply..?? and another thing i found some code use this together like this:

```
  function doSomething() {
    return Function.prototype.call.apply(Array.prototype.slice, arguments);
}
```

are is the same as..

```
Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)
```

Why we want to use call and apply together?

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply

Comment: You can find the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13004493/1064253

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not the same. `Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)` applies the slice function on the current `argument` object, while `Function.prototype.call.apply(Array.prototype.slice, arguments);` calls the slice function on the array which is provided as the first argument.

Maybe things like this will become easier with new EcmaScript syntax. Your `doSomething` is equivalent to

```
function doSomething(array, ...)
    array.slice(...); // assuming array is really an array
}
```

whereas the second is equivalent to

```
function (...) {
    arguments.slice(); // assuming argument objects are actual arrays
}
```

Comment: so statement is equivalent to Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments[0], arguments[1], ...);

Answer (score 1):

ase the same

```
Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)
```

yes, i think its the same too..!!