# Can someone explain this "passing arguments" in javascript example?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, call, apply

I'm reading through [Javascript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/), and I'm trying to wrap my head around the following example:

> **Passing Arguments**
>
> The following is the recommended way of passing arguments from one function to another.
>
> ```
>  function foo() {
>      bar.apply(null, arguments);
>  }
>  function bar(a, b, c) {
>      // do stuff here
>  }
> ```
>
> Another trick is to use both call and apply together to create fast, unbound wrappers.
>
> ```
>  function Foo() {}
>
>  Foo.prototype.method = function(a, b, c) {
>      console.log(this, a, b, c);
>  };
>
>  // Create an unbound version of "method" 
>  // It takes the parameters: this, arg1, arg2...argN
>  Foo.method = function() {
>
>      // Result: Foo.prototype.method.call(this, arg1, arg2... argN)
>      Function.call.apply(Foo.prototype.method, arguments);
>  };
> ```

I'm trying to figure out two things:

1) What exactly is an "unbound wrapper"?

2) How does the chaining from .call to .apply work and/or make the code faster?

Comment: Actually he wanted to do `Foo.method = Function.call.bind(Foo.prototype.method)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"1) What exactly is an "unbound wrapper"?"*

Unbound wrapper is just a function that calls another function by passing on the desired `this` value and arguments.

> *"2) How does the chaining from .call to .apply work and/or make the code faster?"*

The `.call.apply()` is faster than having to do a `.slice()` on the `arguments` to separate the `this` from the actual args.

Otherwise it would need to do this, which is slower:

```
Foo.method = function(ths) {

    Foo.prototype.method.apply(ths, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> What exactly is an "unbound wrapper"?

A function that is not to be called *on* an instance, but *with* an instance as its argument. It's not bound to the prototype / doesn't need to be bound to an instance. Example:

```
var x = new Foo;
// instead of
x.method(1, 2, 3);
// you now call
Foo.method(x, 1, 2, 3);
```

The benefit of this is that you can pass the function around without caring about its `this` context.

> How does the chaining from .call to .apply work and/or make the code faster?

It doesn't really make anything "faster". It's not even compared to any "slower" solution.

For how it works, please check the duplicate question [What's the meaning to chain call and apply together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674115/whats-the-meaning-to-chain-call-and-apply-together).

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be like this:

```
function Foo() {}

Foo.prototype.method = function(a, b, c) {
 console.log(this, a, b, c);
};

Foo.method = function() {

 //Notice this line:
 Function.apply.call(Foo.prototype.method, this, arguments);
};
```

then

```
Foo.method(1,2,3) => function Foo() {} 1 2 3
```

Other examples:

```
Function.apply.call(Array,this,[1,2]) => [1, 2]
Function.call.apply(Array,this,[1,2]) => [window]
Function.call.call(Array,this,[1,2])  => [[1, 2]]
```